# Embedd and Load Dll into Project - VB.NET / C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, resources, fiddler

I am currently programming an analyze program to check for trojans and malware.
For this I also use Fiddler Core to intercept and analyze traffic of those trojans.

**Fiddler Core comes additionally with 3 dlls** which need to be in the same start folder as the program itself. As I want my Startup folder to be Exe only without any additional dlls displayed **I embedded these  3 dlls in my project as resource and load them in ApplicationEvents.**

**This way works with all DLLs except one, the CertMaker.dll.**
It is responsible for creating the root certificate which is needed to intercept the requests.

If I embed the CertMaker.dll it works up to the point that a root certificate is created, but then it does not intercept the requests. I can't get any queries in. **It only works if I write the CertMaker.dll from memory into the startup folder** but as I wrote above I want the startup folder to be the exe only.

**Here is my code in case you need it:**

ApplicationEvents.vb:

```
Namespace My
Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Private WithEvents Domain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    Private Function DomainCheck(sender As Object, e As System.ResolveEventArgs) As System.Reflection.Assembly Handles Domain.AssemblyResolve
        If e.Name.Contains("BCMakeCert") Then
            Return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(My.Resources.Dll1)
        ElseIf e.Name.Contains("CertMaker") Then
            Return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(My.Resources.Dll2)
        ElseIf e.Name.Contains("FiddlerCore4") Then
            Return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(My.Resources.Dll3)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

It works only if I write the CertMaker.dll to the Startup Folder:

```
 Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()
 File.WriteAllBytes(appPath & "/CertMaker.dll", My.Resources.Dll2)
```

**Is there another way to include and load the dll in the project without the dll appearing in the same startup folder**? I would like to be able to send the program later as a file without the dlls being in the folder.

Comment: Please tell me that your not putting the actual EXE in the Startup folder. Don't do that. Put the EXE where you put other programs and put a shortcut in the Startup folder.

Comment: Im not talking about the windows startup folder auto starting applications at windows startup. Im talking about the Application startup folder, the folder where the program is started from. Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()

Comment: So what's the problem with having DLLs in the program folder? I hear many people say they don't want that but am yet to hear a good reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use AppDomain.Current.Load(assembly) method if the fiddler's assemblies are .Net based.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply. I will try that one.

I only have an issue with the CertMaker.dll but it works with all other dlls which Is why I wondered.